MessageBox.Show() 使用時、Windows 11 でタイトルの文字列が見切れる
VB.NETの MessageBox.Show() の仕様について質問です。
MessageBox.Show() で表示されるウインドウで、Windows 10環境ではタイトル部分が見切れることなく表示されておりましたが、Windows 11環境で実行したところ、タイトル部分の文字列が見切れる事象が発生しました。
ソースコードに変更は加えておらず、MessageBox.Show() にはウインドウサイズを手動で変更するようなメソッドは存在せず、タイトルの文字列に合わせて自動でサイズが調整される想定でしたが、Windows 11環境では仕様が異なるのでしょうか？
利用メソッド
MessageBox.Show(strMsg, Caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK)

strMsg：String型文字列
Captyion：String型文字列

回答しようとする人が簡単に問題を再現・検証出来る程度に詳しい情報を追記してください。.NET Framework/Coreの種別や版数、アプリはWinForms/WPFあるいは別の何かの種類か、表示しようとしたメッセージやキャプション文字列の内容とかを具体的にテキストで、そして見切れるという表示結果はスクリーンショットで等。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方, スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？

ウィンドウサイズと文字数に依存する気がするので、実際の表示例 (画面キャプチャ) がそれぞれあった方が状況が伝わりやすいと思います。

Windows10と11でシステム標準フォントが違うのかもしれませんね。10はYu Gothic UIで11でも同じという記事 Windows 11のフォント変更方法は？手順やツールを解説 と11ではSegoe UI Variableになっているという記事 Windows 11 の文字体裁 があるようです。最初の記事に紹介されていた Meiryo UIも大っきらい!! というツールを使ってみるか、APIを使わず独自にカスタマイズしたウインドウを使うとかしてみては？ [C#] メッセージボックスの文字サイズを変更する方法

スクリーンショットをいくつか追加すべきでした...
